# Inspect Events binded to a node with Dev tools

Tags: jquery, events, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way of inspecting jQuery events binded to a node with chrome dev tools?

IE:

```
<div id="aNode">hello</div>

$('aNode').click(function() {...})
```

Thanks

Comment: See my edit 2. It will save your day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Chrome dev-tools, after selecting the element, click on the Event Listeners tab on the right:

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT**

You can also use [Visual Events](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2) bookmarklet. It's a great tool. so easy to use. so handy.

**EDIT 2**

I would also like to point you to [this article](http://www.elijahmanor.com/7-chrome-tips-developers-designers-may-not-know/) that mentions some of other great features of Google Chrome Dev-Tools.

Comment: Nice!  I use Firefox as my main development environment mainly because of Firebug.  I think this is the first feature I have seen elsewhere that I would find useful and that Firebug lacks or doesn't do better